# Setting default values in php

Tags: php, request

I have some values in my query string which i get in PHP using $_REQUEST. I assign these values to their respective variables so that i could do what i want with them, however if the $_REQUEST array is not set i would like to assign default values to variables.  I tried this but i kept getting "undefined index" for both values:

```
$Start = $_REQUEST["start"] ?: 0;
$Fetch = $_REQUEST["fetch"] ?: 2;
```

i would like a way of assigning or setting default values for both variables in case the request array is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if they exist which the shorthand ternary operator does not do:

```
$Start = isset($_REQUEST["start"]) ? $_REQUEST["start"] : 0;
$Fetch = isset($_REQUEST["fetch"]) ? $_REQUEST["fetch"] : 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case, for example:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["start"])) {
    $fetch = ValueResolver::resolve($_REQUEST["fetch"], 2); // returns 2 if $_REQUEST["fetch"] equal to '', 0, false etc.
}
```

and don't forget to use namespace `use LapaLabs\ValueResolver\Resolver\ValueResolver;`

There are also ability to typecasting, for example if your variable's value should be `integer`, so use this:

```
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('6 apples', 2); // returns 6
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('There are no apples', 2); // returns 2 (used default value)
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) for more examples

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 7 you can use the null coalescing operator ([`??`](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)) to do this:

```
$Start = $_REQUEST["start"] ?? 0;
$Fetch = $_REQUEST["fetch"] ?? 2;
```